# Using devise for user registration/login redirect user to a different form page based on their response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise for user registration/login, after the user has successfully signed up, I want to show a page/a dialog box and redirect to another page based on user response. How can I do that?

**User Model (By devise)**

- username
- password

**Student Model**

- name
- student_id

**Teacher Model**

- name
- grade

First_page: 
signup signin links
Signup link will show the devise views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb page.
After successful signup, it takes the user to root page. I have defined the root page in routes.rb:

` Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :students, :teachers

# For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root to: "students#index"
end `

At this point, the application doesn't have any idea who the user is.

So, I want to get the identity information(student/teacher) from the user.

How will I get this information?

Student/Teacher controller:
`class StudentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]
    def index
        @students = Student.all
    end

```
def new
  @student = Student.new
end

def create
  current_user.create_student(student_params)
  redirect_to root_path
end

private
def student_params
  params.require(:student).permit(:name, :skypid)
end
```

end`

After the user has successfully signed in, I want to ask if the user is a student or teacher. Based on what they select, redirect them to a student form page or teacher form page.

How can I do that in rails?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom `after_sign_in_path_for` function in your `ApplicationController` assuming you're using all the default Devise controllers otherwise. Any named path helper or other route that it returns will be where the user is redirected, so you could do something simple like always redirect to a selection page that presents the options and handles the choice on a subsequent action:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  user_type_selection_path # whatever route in your app manages the selection
end
```

Alternately, you could invoke a custom method on the user model in that function to make a choice right there:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  resource.student? ? student_path : teacher_path
end
```

You could hybridize these of course as well to do the latter when the selection has already been made and redirect otherwise, with something similar to the following:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.user_type_chosen?
    resource.student? ? student_path : teacher_path
  else
    user_type_selection_path
end
```

Bear in mind that none of those functions or paths are real, since I can't be more specific on the information you've provided, but hopefully this gets you headed in the right direction. The `after_sign_in_path_for` hook is your primary tool here, unless you get into the world of overriding the default devise controllers and interrupting the usual workflow there to accommodate this step, which doesn't seem strictly necessary by your description.

Comment: Thanks so much for the ideas! I am new to rails. I have a followup question. So if go with the 3rd suggestion, how can I get the response from user? Should I have to show a dialog box to the user after successful signup? I have added more info to my question in regards to the actual code. Thank you

Comment: Putting together a page at user_type_selection_path or equivalent in your implementation which has a simple form that saves the data as necessary to set the user type will work perfectly fine; you could show that after signup, or you could just add a field to the user account sign up form to set that value, depending on how you need to determine it. Then, the the user_type_chosen? check is actually be what (re)triggers that selection if the user hasn't made one when they try to sign in for future attempts.